# How to declare a callback function using a contextual object as "this" in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, callback

What should be the right way to declare a function in order to filter an array of objects?

It could be a method in a class, but it becomes messy when parameters need to be added.

```
this.works = this.base_works.filter(whatever,{some : value});

whatever(x){
 return x.value !== this.some;
}
```

Im not sure that declaring the function on the same general class is clean.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about setting the function as a parameter or defining the callback function in the class?

Comment: create the callback function, the main question is if I should create the callbacks as a part of the main class or as an stand alone function.

Comment: as in outside the class?

Comment: I will prefer as an anonymous class, like a delegate, Do you know if I can do that in TypeScript.

Comment: why not just use arrow functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried the two options, arrow function

```
var myFunction = (x) => {

                return x.category !== undefined && x.category.indexOf(this.current_filter) !== -1;
            }
```

And
normal

```
var myFunction =  function (x) {

                return x.category !== undefined && x.category.indexOf(this.current_filter) !== -1;
            }
```

When I called the the first one, the reference this is to the object. On the latter the reference on this, is just him and his arguments.
The second one is the one that is perfect to use on the array callbacks. Thanks suraj to help me to find the solution!